# Minimum possible value of the probability $P(X=0)$ where X is a discrete non negative random variable

Tags: probability

### ***I have found the following excercise***:

"If X is a non-negative,discrete random variable,taking integer values,find the minimum possible value of $P([X=0])$ given that $E[X]=1$,$E[X^2]=2$ and $E[X^3]=5$

I have tried using Chebyshev's inequality or Markov's inequality but i cannot find a suitable lower bound for $P([X=0])$ and much more i cannot find the minimum possible value for $P([X=0])$ (and what assures us that there is a minimum value and not an infimum ?)

Comment: If you can give an example with $P[X=0]=0$ then you are done.

Comment: You could try solving the system $a+b+c=3$, $a^2+b^2+c^2=6$, $a^3+b^3+c^3=15$. Similar questions have been asked here before.

Comment: @GerryMyerson do u denote $a=P[X=1],b=P[X=2],c=P[X=3]$ if i understand correctly?

Comment: @Math-fun wow..thank you very much my friend

Comment: No, I was taking $P[X=a]=P[X=b]=P[X=c]=1/3$.

Comment: You know, compared to that other question, you left out the very important piece of information that $X$ was restricted to whole number values. Without that restriction, it's a very different problem.

Comment: @GerryMyerson you are wright.I forgot to write that it takes non negative but integer values.